# Extending functions on heterogeneous lists

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, type-level-computation

I have implemented my own `HList` type using [Apocalisp's type-level programming guide](https://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-6a-heterogeneous-list%C2%A0basics/). Now I am trying to implement a function with the following signature:

```
extend : (A => B) => (A ::: R) => (B ::: R)

where
A, B, R <: HList and ':::' is type-level concatenation.
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to isolate the `A` and `R` components of the input list `A ::: R`. **What is the best way to go about this?**

*I can't rely on external libraries such as shapeless, and I won't be using any HList functions apart from append and extend.*